# Can't resolve 'fs' in '{ProjectPath}\node_modules\yamljs\lib'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

Recently I upgraded `react`(v18) and `react-scripts` to v5.

After the upgrade, I am facing the issue "`Can't resolve 'fs'`".
after searching on google and StackOverflow found the only solution was to downgrade the `react-scripts` to v4. Is there another solution available other than this?

1. Downgrade the `react-scripts` to v4
2. Webpack config changes
3. eject the app

Comment: You could try and install the dependency by hand `npm install fs` or `yarn add fs` if you are using Yarn. If that's not working, you could open a bug report on Github for this package. Removing the entire package and reinstall it again, might work as well

Comment: No, its not working - @node_modules